# Why Magento not supporting cart price rule per store

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, sales-rule

Why Magento does not support storeview level sales rules?
Is there any way we can create shopping cart price rules based on store-views?

Discount should apply only for particular store views

Answer (score 1):

Magento just does not support managing Sales Rules per Store View.
You can manage it by Websites and CustomerGroups and so on.

If You need that functionality, You have to implement it or install an external extension that would provide it.
For example:
https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-shopping-cart-price-rule-per-store-view-extension.html
or
https://www.magespark.com/magento-2-catalog-price-rule-per-store-view.html